I want to run Python processing in VS Code but processing-py.jar does not exist
I would like to be able to processing on VS Code since it's just a better IDE and it would make what I am doing right now faster.
I searched many tutorials up but they all require you to have the processing-py.jar file and that's the only thing I can't seem to find anywhere.
Image of where it should be:

I also downloaded processing python from this github repo:
but I still couldn't find any existence of processing-py.jar which is what I need.

Did what you want to do work in some other IDE? Also since VSCode itself doesn't run things, are you looking for an Extension to run Java, for example? Where does it say that you need that Jar-File? Can you link one of the tutorials or provide code along with an error message?

https://discourse.processing.org/t/tutorial-running-python-mode-in-vscode/7716
i cant find the jar file so I dont have any errors, it just wont work without it

Have you seen this: https://pypi.org/project/processing-py/

Try pip3 install processing-py in a Terminal window of vscode.

This probably would work but I am using processing for school related projects and I need to be able to use the original processing code layouts with def draw(): and def setup(): so my teacher could also run the projects.

Processing 4 no longer supports Python.  You can post in their forum for confirmation and other options that might be available.

Caveat about the previous comments mentioning processing-py on PyPI, that is an unrelated dead project, not based on Processing Python mode's processing-py.jar!

Using Processing Python mode's processing-py.jar (to use other IDEs) was unsupported by the maintainer, JDF, for years. That's why the jar was not easily available. And now, to compound the problem, the project has no active maintainer anymore.
If you want to use VS Code and something similar to Processing Python mode, I recommend https://py5coding.org, a new and well maintained project that is kind of a spiritual heir to Processing Python mode.
It uses the Processing 4 Java core jars and Python (thanks to jpype, CPython 3, instead of zombie Jython 2.7)
I myself prefer to use py5 + Thonny IDE https://abav.lugaralgum.com/como-instalar-py5/index-EN.html but you get to choose: https://py5coding.org/content/install.html
Caveat about the previous comments mentioning processing-py on PyPI, that is an unrelated dead project, not based on Processing Python mode's processing-py.jar!
